# Binary Search on

Tags: python

I am trying to apply a binary search on the following:

```
### START FUNCTION
def binary_search(f,domain, MAX = 1000):

### END FUNCTION
f = lambda x:(np.sin(x)**2)*(x**2)-2
domain = (0,2)
x=binary_search(f,domain)
x
```

1.43
Expected output

```
binary_search(lambda x:(np.sin(x)**2)*(x**2)-2,(0,2))==1.43
```

How do I apply a binary search to the above?

Comment: You'll need to fill in a definition for `binary_search`.  Since you have given *no* description of what it should do, you won't likely get much help here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a new user, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask].
It might also help to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: What exactly are you searching *for*? Zero?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're looking for `f(x) == 0`, you use the same method as for any binary search:

- Examine the midpoint of the domain
- If `f(x)` is zero, you have found `x`

  - In your case: if you have done `MAX` iterations, take `x` as your approximation
- Otherwise, halve the domain and search again in the appropriate half depending on whether `f(x)` is negative or positive